# Why Would A Recruiter Ask To Remove Contact Details From My CV/Resume?

Tags: resume, recruitment, contact

So I'm looking for potential jobs, I got in contact with an agency and they came back with 5 ideal positions and another 5 a few days later (my job role is in-demand right now) so I sent them my CV and they said it looks great however the one thing they want me to change is the fact that I have my contact details written on it... Which is, in my opinion totally normal for a CV, in fact I believe it's one of the most important things, I mean, what kind of idiot applies for a job but doesn't leave a clue how to get back to them? I don't want the employers thinking I'm a moron but at the same time I think I should just do what the recruiters ask because they're very successful in this industry.

Also I feel like my name is better than any phone number or email address because it is so unique, If an employer were to search my name in Google they would instantly find me and no one else. Is there a chance that the recruiters will remove/change my name from the application? Because without that I'm just a ghost so I feel that would hinder my application in comparison to an application where there is a name, so the employer can read it and (slightly) connect with the applicant on a personal level.

Comment: maybe recruiter just want everything to go through them? This way they know how many candidates they have supplied and how many got the job for a fact. I guess employers are paying per each hired person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A variety of reasons are possible.

First, you are not the point of contact if you are applying through a recruiter.  They remove your contact information to avoid any confusion on this part.  It's unlikely this will reflect on you in any way.

> Because without that I'm just a ghost so I feel that would hinder my application in comparison to an application where there is a name, so the employer can read it and (slightly) connect with the applicant on a personal level.

Some companies want to minimize any bias based on name purely. There have been a lot of research studies into this over the years. It's possible either the companies/agency involved do this as a precaution.

> I don't want the employers thinking I'm a moron but at the same time I think I should just do what the recruiters ask because they're very successful in this industry.

That's how a lot of recruiters work. *You* aren't applying to the company individually, but through an agency. That's how *they* work (for better or worse).

Comment: Cheers for the insight, this is the first time I've actually used a recruiter for job hunting.

Comment: A PDF does not prevent them from editing your resume.  Only a digital signature can do that, and it only prevents them from editing that document, not the contents of that document pasted into another document.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings sure, but a PDF is a lot harder to edit than a .docx  for the casual editor ;)

Comment: @enderland - These guys edit resumes for a living(the ones that you want to avoid anyway) a PDF is not going to stop that.

Answer (score 6):

> Why Would A Recruiter Ask To Remove Contact Details From My CV/Resume?

The thing is that you are doing this through a **Contract Agency**.

Including your personal contact details could end up in them calling you *directly* if they find you a good candidate, when in this situation this should be done through the agency (as they are your point of contact and probably with the ones you have some agreement or contract).

> Is there a chance that the recruiters will remove/change my name from the application?

You name I doubt it, but that would be guessing. Any contact info *could* be removed though, for the reasons above explained.

You came to them so they could expose you (basically provide you a service) to potential companies, so they did the finding and networking job for you in your job hunt. If you then try to make an agreement with those possible companies on your own would be harmful for the Contracting Agency, as **that is what they do for a living**.

Comment: I had a feeling this may be the case but then again, even if I do get the job via direct contact from the employer then the recruiter would still be entitled to their fees and bonuses because they would know that I, the applicant ended up at the company and it was arranged by the recruiters.

Comment: @user59347 except that if the employer contacted you directly, it's most likely because they were specifically trying to avoid having to pay those fees and bonuses, which means they would be motivated to not inform the recruiter that they had hired you. Thus, the recruiter would not "know that I, the applicant ended up at the company and it was arranged by the recruiters."

Answer (score 2):

Recruiters get paid by companies for finding them applicants that eventually get hired. This recruiter likely wants your contact information removed so that it is harder for the companies to go around the recruiter and contact you directly.

This request is a bit odd. I've never encountered it. However, I have often been asked for a Word copy of my Resume rather than PDF, and maybe this is so the recruiter can remove my contact details (pure speculation).

This request doesn't seem that unreasonable to me. I would suggest supplying this recruiter with two copies of your resume; one with contact detail, and one without. They can choose which one to use. Remember their goals are pretty well aligned with yours, so if otherwise this recruiter seems legit, this isn't a red flag.

Comment: You don't need to speculate: that's *exactly* the reason a Word document is requested. The recruiter may even reformat it to a standard (so that all the CVs they forward for a post are on an even footing), destroying all the effort you put into laying it out.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I know that at least one recruiter I've worked with does exactly that. Though, I'm not sure why they couldn't copy and paste out of a PDF into a Word template to achieve the same result.

Comment: @DanH You may have noticed the slight bitterness in my comment!